# Prove that, for each a ∈ R, either $a$ is a zero-divisor or a is a unit.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know similar question has been asked here before, but the answers were little bit stronger for me to digest :) So, I am asking the same question again.

Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring with unity.

1.Prove that, for each $a ∈ R$, either $a$ is a zero-divisor or a is a unit.

I was studying a proof almost similar to this on the internet, and the middle proof is like this:
"Consider the set ${\{a^n| n ∈ N} = {a,a^2,a^3,...\}}$. Since $R$ is finite, we must have $a^i = a^j$ for some $i,j$ with $i > j$."

You can refer to this proof [here](https://suu.edu/faculty/markmeilstrup/algebra/Math4220Solutions13a.pdf):

My question is why we must assume $a^i = a^j$ when $i > j$?

I would really appreciate some detail overview on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list $a, a^2, a^3, \ldots$ is an infinite list, but the elements in this list come from a finite set $R$.  That means there must be repeats in the list.  The indices $i$ and $j$ are just the locations where a repeat is found.

For example if we had $a, a^2 = b, a^3 = c, a^4 = d, a^5 = c, a^6 = d$, $\ldots$ then $a^5 = c = a^3$ is a repeat so I could choose $i = 5$ and $j = 3$ to get $a^i = a^j$.

In the proof you reference the assumption $a^i = a^j$ then lets them conclude $a^{i - j} = 1$ because they have already proven that you can cancel $a^j$ from both sides.

Comment: So, you're saying in a finite set, we can automatically assume there are some elements in that set could be similar to others. Am I getting this right?

Comment: No, different elements are always distinct.  But if your set has, for example, only $3$ elements, then the longest list you can make without repeating is $3$.  Once you've listed all $3$ elements the next element in your list will be a repeat, because there's no fourth element for you to choose, you have to choose one of the three again.

Comment: Hmm that makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: by the pigeon hole principle.

In other words, the function: $f:\mathbb N\to R:n\mapsto a^n$ is not injective because, $\mathbb N$ is infinite and $R$ is finite.

Recall that if we assume that $f:\mathbb N\to R$ is injective, then will get $\mathrm{card}(\mathbb N)\leq\mathrm{card}(R)$. a contradiction.

Since $f$ is not injective, there exists $i,j\in\mathbb N$ such that $i\neq j$ and $f(i)= f(j)$, that's $a^i=a^j$.
Without lost of generality we can assume $i<j$.

Comment: I'd like to let you know about [this post on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19593/deleted-answer-from-question) which is related to answer of yours. After you read this comment, you can either flag it as obsolete or [ping me in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138) so that I can come and delete this comment. (It is entirely unrelated to this post, but I wanted to ping you somewhere and let you know about the post on meta.)

Answer (score 0):

Assume by contradiction that the elements don't repeat. Let $n$ be the number of elements in $R$.

Then $R$ contains the $n+1$ distinct elements $a,a^2, a^3,.., a^n, a^{n+1}$, which means that $R$ contains at least $n+1$ elements. This contradicts the fact that $R$ contains exactly $n$ elements. CONTRADICTION.

We proved that the powers of $a$ repeat. This means that we can find two different powers $a^i, a^j$ which are equal. As $ i\neq j$ it means that either $i <j$ or $i>j$, and by symmetry we can assume the first  (if we are in the second case we just interchange i and j).